# iOS 17.0, Sign in with Apple, Error Domain=AKAuthenticationError Code=-7091 "(null)" and error 1000

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, cloudkit

In my app I am Signing in with Apple which works just fine.
Checklist:

- Sign in with Apple capabilities added for both Debug and Release.
  [image]

- Please note that some of these are also configured for CloudKit.

Signing in works just fine.

However, on the relaunch, when I want to check that login state, I execute this code

```swift
    private func checkLoginStatus() {
        Task {
            do {
                let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
                let credentialState = try await appleIDProvider.credentialState(forUserID: KeychainItem.currentUserIdentifier)
                if credentialState == .authorized {
                    withAnimation {
                        self.isLoggedIn = true
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
```

This code always throws:

> Thread 5: Fatal error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.AuthenticationServices.AuthorizationError error 1000.)

Briefly before that however, I get:

> Credential State request returned with error: Error Domain=AKAuthenticationError Code=-7091 "(null)"

The solution is mostly replicated from Juice Sample App from Apple.
I ran out of ideas what's wrong here. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I ran the juice code and I think that the first error, 1000, is just because you are not yet authenticated. In my case the KeychainItem.currentUserIdentifier was empty (""), so it should show the login screen first. However, just as you found, the ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider call fails. I noticed that other people reported that the juice app doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a silly mistake by not checking the implementation of the Keychain item from the Juice sample project.

If someone encounters the issue with this sample project, I recommend looking for an answer in the keychain Item.

Here is a very simple Session manager implementation:

```swift
import AuthenticationServices

class SessionManager {
    static let shared = SessionManager()
    
    private init() {
//        deleteKeychainItem(service: "your.bundle", account: "appleIDToken") // If your data is corrupted
    }
    
    func saveToKeychain(appleIDCredential: ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential) {
        do {
            let encodedCredential = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: appleIDCredential, requiringSecureCoding: true)

            let keychainQuery: [String: Any] = [
                kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword,
                kSecAttrService as String: "your.bundle",
                kSecAttrAccount as String: "appleIDToken",
                kSecValueData as String: encodedCredential,
                kSecAttrAccessible as String: kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked
            ]

            let status = SecItemAdd(keychainQuery as CFDictionary, nil)
            if status == errSecSuccess {
                print("Token stored in Keychain successfully")
            } else if status == errSecDuplicateItem {
                print("Token already exists in Keychain")
            } else {
                print("Error storing token in Keychain with status: \(status)")
                // Handle the error appropriately
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error encoding credential: \(error)")
        }
    }

        
    func retrieveFromKeychain() -> ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential? {
        let keychainQuery: [String: Any] = [
            kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword,
            kSecAttrService as String: "your.bundle",
            kSecAttrAccount as String: "appleIDToken",
            kSecReturnData as String: true,
            kSecMatchLimit as String: kSecMatchLimitOne
        ]

        var result: AnyObject?
        let status = SecItemCopyMatching(keychainQuery as CFDictionary, &result)

        if status == errSecSuccess, let tokenData = result as? Data {
            do {
                if let credential = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential.self, from: tokenData) {
                    return credential
                } else {
                    print("Credential could not be unarchived")
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error decoding credential: \(error)")
            }
        } else if status == errSecItemNotFound {
            print("Token not found in Keychain")
        } else {
            print("Error retrieving token from Keychain with status: \(status)")
        }
        return nil
    }

    func deleteKeychainItem(service: String, account: String) {
        let keychainQuery: [String: Any] = [
            kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword,
            kSecAttrService as String: service,
            kSecAttrAccount as String: account,
        ]
        
        let status = SecItemDelete(keychainQuery as CFDictionary)
        if status == errSecSuccess {
            print("Keychain item deleted successfully")
        } else if status == errSecItemNotFound {
            print("Keychain item not found")
        } else {
            print("Error deleting Keychain item with status: \(status)")
        }
    }
}
```